# How to check if array contains boolean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

```
// Create a function named 'containsBool'that accepts an 

// array as a parameter.

// You can remove the comments and use the following array: 

// myArray = ['Wednesday',23,false];

// Create a for / in loop inside the function that iterates 

// through the items in the array.

// In the loop, check each array item for 'typeof' data.

// If the array contains Boolean data, return true.

// Likewise, if the array does not contain Boolean data, return false.

// Call the function and log the returned Boolean to the console.
```

Here is my code, I don't know where it doesn't work:

```js
var myArray = ['Wednesday', 23, true];
function containsBool(checkBool) {
  for (g in checkBool) {
    if (typeof checkBool[g] === 'boolean') {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

console.log(containsBool(myArray));
```

Comment: `for...in` is not made to iterate over arrays. Use `for...of`.

Comment: [Don't use `for…in` enumerations on arrays!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)

Comment: You must not `return false` when you have met the first (any) non-boolean value, you must do it when you have met none in the whole array - after the loop.

Comment: @Bergi *// Create a for / in loop inside the function that iterates

// through the items in the array.* The assignment asks him explicitly to use `for...in`.

Comment: @connexo Oh well, I didn't read that, but it's wrong nonetheless. The assignment explicitly asking for this can only be seen as an indication on the quality of the course…

Comment: Thank you, Bergi. I was wondering why it works when the 'return false' outside the 'for' loop? Then I saw your comments.  Thank you for sharing the link.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to be aware that **`return` ends the `for...in` loop**. It's okay to end it early if you found a boolean. If the loop never finds a Boolean, it reaches `return false`.

Please note that to iterate over an array, you need to use `for...of`, not `for...in`.

```js
const myArray = ['Wednesday', 23, true];
function containsBool(checkBool) {
  for (arrayEntry of checkBool) {
    if (typeof arrayEntry === 'boolean') {
      return true;
    } 
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(containsBool(myArray));
```

For a more modern, ES6 version, you can use `Array.prototype.some`:

```js
const myArray = ['Wednesday', 23, true];

console.log(myArray.some(entry => typeof entry === 'boolean'));
```

Comment: The person -1ing, please explain. This is exactly what the assignment asks OP to do.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your code really helps me solve this problem. I was wondering why it works when the 'return false' outside the 'for' loop?

Comment: Then I saw "You must not return false when you have met the first (any) non-boolean value, you must do it when you have met none in the whole array - after the loop. – Bergi "

Comment: @Bergi I think you might have downvoted for the lack of correction of OP using for...in on arrays. I changed that.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem statement is not too specific to the implementation(for loop or whatever...) then this does the same job:

```
['Wednesday', 23, true].some((x)=> typeof x === 'boolean')
```

Comment: var myArray2 = ['Wednesday', 23, false];
function checkBoolean2(boolCheck) {
 if(boolCheck.some((x)=> typeof x === 'boolean')){
   return true;
   } else {
    return false;
   }
}

console.log(checkBoolean2(myArray2));

Answer (score -1):

This should do the job:

```js
var someArray = ['Wednesday', 23, true];
function checkBoolean() {

    for (i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
        if (typeof someArray[i] === "boolean") {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

console.log(checkBoolean(someArray));
```

In your case, should not use `for...in` loops to loop over the array. (Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea) why.)
You also should look at your `else` statement. If the entry to check is not an boolean (which happens twice), the function will return false. `return` stop executing the function so the loop gets executed only once.

Comment: Thank you for giving me a link why not use 'for...in' loops.